# How to customize the label displayed for a ManyToManyField in an inline model admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Let's suppose I have the following model definition:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
```

Now let's suppose I want to register the models with the admin site, using an inline model admin to allow toppings to be added while editing pizzas:

```
@admin.register(Topping)
class ToppingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class ToppingInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Pizza.toppings.through
    verbose_name = 'topping'
    verbose_name_plural = 'toppings'

@admin.register(Pizza)
class PizzaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('toppings',)
    inlines = (ToppingInline,)
```

This leads to a rather glaring issue:

[image]

As you can see, the label is ugly. Is there a way to customize it?

Answer (score 3):

An quicker and dirtier alternative to defining a model class for the relationship is to redefine the `__str__` or `__unicode__` method:

```
class ToppingInline(admin.TabularInline):
    ...
    Pizza.toppings.through.__str__ = lambda self: 'Topping'
```

Comment: Both answers are right but I personally prefer this one as you're not having to create a model that you would otherwise not need to.  Plus it  still works with Django 3.1 and unless the models themselves have a big overhaul it won't go away anytime soon

Comment: Great idea! Way cleaner than creating a model you don't need!

Answer (score 2):

[You would control what displays for an object using the `__str__` or `__unicode__` method.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#str)

[You could manage the many to many yourself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) to define this attribute like this:

```
...

class Pizza(models.Model):
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, through="PizzaToppingRelationship")


class PizzaToppingRelationship(models.Model):
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza)
    topping = models.ForeignKey(Topping)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Pizza Topping - {}'.format(self.topping.name)
```